# Child list in join statement - LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have 3 collections

```
List<Brand> brands= new List<Brand>
{
    new Brand { ID = 5, Name = "Toyota"},
    new Brand { ID = 6, Name = "Mazda"},
    new Brand { ID = 7, Name = "Seat"}
};


ModelParam par1 = new ModelParam() { Id = 1, fuelType = "Petrol", enginePower =110, engineTorque = 130 };
ModelParam par2 = new ModelParam() { Id = 2, fuelType = "Petrol", enginePower = 170, engineTorque = 290 };
ModelParam par3 = new ModelParam() { Id = 3, fuelType = "Diesel", enginePower = 140, engineTorque = 280 };
ModelParam par4 = new ModelParam() { Id = 4, fuelType = "Diesel", enginePower = 190, engineTorque = 320 };

List<Model> models = new List<Model>
{
    new Model { Id = 1, Name = "CX5", brandId = 6, parameters = new List<ModelParam> {par1, par3} },
    new Model { Id = 2, Name = "Corolla", brandId = 5, parameters = new List<ModelParam> {par2, par3} },
    new Model { Id = 3, Name = "Leon", brandId = 7, parameters = new List<ModelParam> {par2, par4} }
};
```

As a result I want to have a query with combination of:
Brand - Model - FuelType - EnginePower.
I wrote this to join brands and model lists:

```
var result = models.Join(brands, 
    mod => mod.brandId, 
    b => b.ID, 
    (mod, b) => new { b.Name, mod.Name })
.ToList();
```

The problem is I can't extract `fuelType` and `enginePower` from `ModelParams` from params property in models List. Any tips?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: `params` isn't a valid variable name, please share your actual code. `refMarka` property is also missing

Comment: @Fourat When creating new type I did something like ```new { b.Name, mod.Name, pow = mod.parameters.Select( x => x.enginePower) } ``` - it didn't return value but type of that property

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Whoops, my bad, edited.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your result selector `Func` a little bit and get the required values `fuelType` and `enginePower` from `parameters` collection in `Model` class. The following snippet will select only the first `fuelType` from parameters and max `enginePower`.

```cs
var result = models
    .Join(brands, mod => mod.brandId, b => b.ID,
    (mod, b) => new
    {
        Brand = b.Name,
        Model = mod.Name,
        FuelType = mod.parameters.Select(p => p.fuelType).FirstOrDefault(),
        EnginePower = mod.parameters.Max(p => p.enginePower)
    })
    .ToList();
```

However, there a situation when model can have multiple values for `fuelType` and `enginePower`.

If you need to choose all combinations, just look through the `parameters` collection and then flatten a result using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
var result = models
    .Join(brands, mod => mod.brandId, b => b.ID,
    (mod, b) => mod.parameters.Select(p => new
    {
        Brand = b.Name,
        Model = mod.Name,
        FuelType = p.fuelType,
        EnginePower = p.enginePower
    }))
    .SelectMany(_ => _)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Works fine, but I want to get all combinations, not only first, e.g: Mazda - CX5 - 110, Mazda-CX5-140

Answer (score 1):

Can this approach work for you?

```cs
var result = models.Join(
    brands,
    mod => mod.brandId,
    b => b.ID,
    (mod, b) => mod.parameters.Select(parameter => new { 
       Brand = b.Name,
       Model = mod.Name,
       FuelType = parameter.fuelType,
       EnginePower = parameter.enginePower 
    }))
       .SelectMany(pr => pr)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes! That was exactly what I was looking for.